# Is the constraint $xy\leqslant 0.001$ convex?

Tags: convex-optimization

I would like to ask whether the constraint $xy\leqslant 0.001$ ($x,y\geqslant0$) is convex.

Since its Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite for $x,y\geqslant0$, the constraint $xy\leqslant 0.001$ ($x,y\geqslant0$) is convex. Is it correct?

Comment: The hessian is not positive semidefinite

Comment: Thank you. But if my calculation is correct, its hessian matrix is [0,1] (first row), [1,0] (second row).

Comment: The hessian should be a $2\times 2$ matrix ...

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Why do you think, that this matrix is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Because [x,y]TH[x,y]>=0. Anyway I am not sure whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: The matrix is not positive semidefinite. Try to find an example for $x,y$.

Comment: I see. Is it because the domain of x and y should be R, not R+.

Comment: Yes. Better not reuse variables with different meaning.

Comment: Thank you. But then I have another question. What about x^1.5<=5, is it convex?

Comment: Is it's derivative increasing?

Comment: I mean, for the original problem, I have enforced the domain of x and y to be R+. Why is it not sufficient for [x,y]TH[x,y]>=0?

Comment: These are two different pairs of $x,y$

Comment: What does two different pairs of x,y mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that a twice differentiable function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ on a convex and open set $U\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is convex if and only if the hessian $\nabla^2 f(x,y)$ is positive semidefinite for every $(x,y)\in U$. Concerning your function $f(x,y) = xy$, we have
$$ \nabla^2 f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, $$
which is indefinite, as its eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$.

However, the convexity of $f$ is sufficient but not necessary for the convexity of the sublevel set $S = \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid f(x,y) \le 10^{-3}, x,y\ge 0 \}$.
To show that $S$ is not convex, consider $(x_1, y_1) = (1,0)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (0,1)$. Both are elements of $S$.
However, 
$$\frac12((x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2)) = \left(\frac12, \frac12\right)$$ is not an element of $S$, as
$$ f\left(\frac12, \frac12\right) = \frac14 > 10^{-3}. $$

Comment: Thank you. The explanation of the nonconvex set is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture: the upper boundary is a hyperbola, with the same shape as
$$x=1/y.$$
If you choose two points far out in the legs, the line segment between them will cut above the curve, so it's not convex.

(The solutions by way of the Hessian of the defining function essentially exhibit exactly this counterexample in a less visual, more general way.)